# TCP handshake time is too long

Tags: tcp

I uploaded the api server. And I made a local call to postman, and the TCP handshake takes more than 10 seconds.

Not all calls are like that, 1-2 out of 10 are.
I'm not sure which part to check to fix this.
Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Sounds like you’ve got an intermittent internet connection.  Try pinging the server and see if it reports any dropped packets or large variation in round-trip times.